# How do I get exact CPU temps using CMD/WMIC?

Tags: cmd, windows-8.1, wmic

I am busy making a program to check what the CPU temperature is so that I can get notified and save my work in order to shut down the laptop and let it cool down.
I started testing if this works and used this command (with admin privileges):

```
:start
sleep 1
cls
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature /value') do set /a "HunDegCel=(%%~A*10)-27315"
echo %HunDegCel:~0,-2%.%HunDegCel:~-2% Degrees Celsius
goto start
pause
```

The output text stayed at ***27.85 Degrees Celcius***

Apparently, this is the reading of an area on the motherboard, not the CPU. Would anyone know what I should use to get the reading and be able to use it as a variable? I'd prefer it to be for CMD, but it can also be for WMIC.

**Laptop Specs:**

Windows 8.1 64-bit (With Windows Resource Kit 2003 installed)

CPU: Intel Pentium N3520 @ 2.16GHz

Motherboard: Hewlett-Packard 2213

RAM: 4,00GB DDR3 @ 666MHz

Comment: Would PowerShell be an option (rather than CMD) ?

Comment: @Abra I have no experience with PowerShell. But I'll see what I can do.

Comment: If it is indeed supported on your PC, _(the majority don't)_, that would only provide the temperature for a zone _(of your case)_, when a thermal event occurred, not the current temperature of the zone, and certainly not your CPU temperture, _(which I think for your specific CPU, would have a max of around 100°C, and in general use would not reach temperatures much more that around half of that)_.